# Merge and broadcast, building a (simple) Akka graph

Tags: scala, akka

The Akka documentation is vast and there are a lot of tutorials. But either they are outdated or they only cover the basics (or, maybe I simply can't find the right ones).

What I want to create is a websocket application with multiple clients and multiple sources on the server side. As I don't want to get over my head from the start, I want to make baby steps and incrementally increase the complexity of the software I am building.

After toying around with some simple flows I wanted to start with a more sophisticated graph now.

What I want is:

Two sources, one that pushes "keepAlive" messages from the server to the client (currently only one) and a second one that actually pushes useful data.

Now for the first one I have this:

```
val tickingSource: Source[Array[Byte], Cancellable] =
  Source.tick(initialDelay = 1 second, interval = 10 seconds, tick = NotUsed)
        .zipWithIndex
        .map{ case (_, counter) => SomeMessage().toByteArray}
```

Where `SomeMessage` is a protobuf type.

Because I can't find an up-to-date way to add an actor as a source, I tried the following for my second source:

```
val secondSource = Source(1 to 1000)
val secondSourceConverter = Flow[Int].map(x => BigInteger.valueOf(x).toByteArray)
```

My attempt at the graph:

```
val g: RunnableGraph[NotUsed] = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create()
{
  implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val sourceMerge = builder.add(Merge[Array[Byte]](2).named("sourceMerge"))

  val x = Source(1 to 1000)

  val y = Flow[Int].map(x => BigInteger.valueOf(x).toByteArray)

  val out = Sink.ignore
  tickingSource ~> sourceMerge ~> out
  x ~> y ~> sourceMerge

  ClosedShape
})
```

Now `g` is of type `RunnableGraph[NotUsed]` while it should be `RunnableGraph[Array[Byte]]` for my websocket. And I wonder here: am I already doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Source.queue helped me to replace my Actor sources.

Comment: @kardapoltsev How do you pass the reference to the source to the actor?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `secondSourceConverter` into the `GraphDSL.create`, like the following example taken from their [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html). Here they import 2 sinks, but it's the same technique.

```
RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(topHeadSink, bottomHeadSink)((_, _)) { implicit builder =>
  (topHS, bottomHS) =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  Source.single(1) ~> broadcast.in

  broadcast.out(0) ~> sharedDoubler ~> topHS.in
  broadcast.out(1) ~> sharedDoubler ~> bottomHS.in
  ClosedShape
})
```

Comment: Still get a `RunnableGraph[(Cancellable, NotUsed)]` :(

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

Your graph is of type `RunnableGraph[NotUsed]` because you're using `Sink.ignore`. And you probably want a `RunnableGraph[Future[Array[Byte]]]` instead of a `RunnableGraph[Array[Byte]]`:

```
val byteSink = Sink.fold[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]](Array[Byte]())(_ ++ _)

val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(byteSink) { implicit builder => bSink =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val sourceMerge = builder.add(Merge[Array[Byte]](2))
  tickingSource ~> sourceMerge ~> bSink.in
  secondSource ~> secondSourceConverter ~> sourceMerge

  ClosedShape
})
// RunnableGraph[Future[Array[Byte]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you would like to process incoming messages but here is a simple example. Hope that it'll help you.

```
path("ws") {
   extractUpgradeToWebSocket { upgrade =>
    complete {
      import scala.concurrent.duration._
      val tickSource = Source.tick(1.second, 1.second, TextMessage("ping"))
      val messagesSource = Source.queue(10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      messagesSource.mapMaterializedValue { queue =>
        //do something with out queue
        //like myHandler ! RegisterOutQueue(queue)
      }
      val sink = Sink.ignore
      val source = tickSource.merge(messagesSource)
      upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(
        inSink = sink,
        outSource = source
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is irrelevant. He's asking about building a graph, you're showing how to use Akka HTTP.

Comment: Actually `mapMaterializedValue` returns a new source. But thanks a lot :)